# How can I initialize a matriz with a char. I am trying to do rooster game and I need at the beginning to have a matrix 3x3 with "-"

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to do rooster game and I need at the beginning to have a matrix 3x3 with "-""

```
char matrix[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
              matrix[i][j]= "-";
         }
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `"-"` is not `'-'`

Comment: `memset()` is another option

Answer (score 1):

**Mistake:** char is to be quoted within single quotes('a').

Also there is no need of newline. Loop is doing it already.

```
char matrix[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
              matrix[i][j]= '-';
        }
}
```

Good Luck!